# error making dll

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, c#-2.0, dllexport, aspnet-compiler

I created ASP.NET pages using C# code when I compile the (.csproj file) code using COMPILE.BAT file it shows me compilation error with error code cs1303 [ "Label01" not found, "TextBox01" not found" so on... as all forms are unable to make dll...

I wanna compile all the code to make a dll file but I cannot compile it.... Anybody please help me....

Comment: What is `COMPILE.BAT` and what does it contain?

Comment: compile.bat is a file used to compile a .csproj file it consists of the following code... "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe karthik.csproj /p:Configuration=Release"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that designer file is missing in your context. Try adding it.